# R Packages Source File

Tags: r, package, datasource

We want to investigate R packages for data-security.
In R packages there are many files.

Which one is the source file? Which one should we investigate?

Thank You!

Comment: All R code in an R package goes to the `R` directory. Inspect all files that are located in this folder.

Comment: I think you should investigate all files, but in particular in addition to those in the *R*  subdirectory also those in the *src* subdirectory.

Comment: To expand a bit on @Roland 's excellent suggestion, the R code in a package should be in the `R` subdirectory, so you need to check that, but code that will be compiled such as C or C++ code will be found in the `src` subdirectory, so you need to check that too. Additionally, in some cases, a package may even have code that it calls from the `inst` subdirectory, such as Perl or python scripts, or header files relied on by scripts in `src` (if they want to make those headers available to other packages), so you *also* need to check that too if it exists

Comment: thank you all! I am checking!